# UIAlertView not showing error when photo fails to save

Tags: objective-c, ios, error-handling, uiimage, uialertview

I'm struggling again, this time getting an alert view to show correct error info, I have got a 2 finger tap gesture that when you click for example a google images (FULL SIZE) image with 2 fingers it saves the image and displays the correct alert "Image Saved" but you could click anywhere with 2 fingers and it says "Image Saved" even though it hasn't as there was no image to save. So if anyone could help me to display a message when they do the gesture on something other than an image
Here is the full code the problem may be elsewhere as the *tagname variable is also unused
Thanks in advance

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

//DoubleTap Gesture
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


}
//Double Tap Method
-(void) doubleTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {
int scrollPositionY = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
int scrollPositionX = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageXOffset"] intValue];

int displayWidth = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.outerWidth"] intValue];
CGFloat scale = myWebView.frame.size.width / displayWidth;

CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:self.myWebView];
pt.x *= scale;
pt.y *= scale;
pt.x += scrollPositionX;
pt.y += scrollPositionY;

NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).tagName", pt.x, pt.y];
NSString * tagName = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", startPoint.x, startPoint.y];
NSString *urlToSave = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSave];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
}
//Alert for double tap save photo
- (void)   savedPhotoImage:(UIImage *)image
  didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
           contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
UIAlertView *alert;

// Unable to save the image
if (error)
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                       message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
else // All is well
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                       message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Comment: So wait, do you want to show an error when the image doesn't exist, or when the user taps anything other than the image?

Comment: After else, put a { and put a closing after [alert show]; }. [alert show] is now getting executed all the time

Comment: Please show the code where you add the tap gesture recognizer and how you use it, i think that the problem is there.

Comment: is savedPhotoImage called on a thread other than the main thread? If so, this would be a reason for the alert failing to show

Comment: Okay so after looking at your code, one of two things could be happening, the image might be nil because the url to save is not returning a valid image url or, since you are downloading the image over the internet, the image data has not completed coming in when you call writeToSavedPhotoAlbum.  Put a break point on the writeToSavedPhotoAlbum line and check out what image and url are holding at that point.

Comment: I have tried the break point when the image is fullsize the *urlToSave has a url but when the image is a thumbnail it's  urlToSave __NSCFConstantString * 0x03bd3d90 and there is no dropdown any ideas how to correct it or is the method bad . thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
if (error)
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                   message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
else // All is well.
   //Without a curly brace here, only one line will get executed. If you want [alert show] to get executed, you have to put a curly brace above and right after wards
  {
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                   message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
 }
}
```

Comment: I believe the intent of the original code is to have the creation in the if/else block and the show to be common code for both cases.

Comment: Yeah It's still giving the message with the added brace, and yep savedPhoto image only appears in the above code, nowhere else. For testing I moved the method into an action sheet button and it's the same it only saves an image when the image is the only thing on the screen like when you click view full size image in google images it will save it, when you try anywhere else it dosent save anything but the alert says success, Any ideas guys

Comment: Also the * tagName variable is unused when I save the image, But i'm a little out of my depth to be honest